# JSON schema validation failed. Array value found, but a null or an object is required. - in JMeter due to special characters in the List values

Tags: arrays, json, validation, jmeter, schema

**In Brief:**

I'm getting (

> JSON schema validation failed. Array value found, but a null or an
> object is required

) error message on the Response Payload for a custom HTTPS Sample Request payload that I created using BeanShell PreProsser to send couple of Arrays.

**STEP 1:**

I'm using BeanShell PreProcessor to create and object from the data available in a CSV file (sampleGroups.csv) as below:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

ArrayList stl = new ArrayList();  
int count = 1;

int limit = ${__P(upcLimit,101)};    

try {
File file = new File (${__P(data1, "sampleGroups.csv")});

if (!file.exists()) {
    throw new Exception ("ERROR: file not found");
}

BufferedReader bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line = null;

while(((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null) && (count < limit))
{
    stl.add(line);
    count++;
}

bufRdr.close();   
}
catch (Exception ex) {
IsSuccess = false; 
log.error(ex.getMessage());
System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}
catch (Throwable thex) {
System.err.println(thex.getMessage());
}
vars.putObject("groups",stl);
```

**STEP 2:**

Then added the "groups" object in the main Request Payload to make an array as below:

```
{
  "included": {
    "groups": ${groups},
    "tags": ${tags}
  }
}
```

> NOTE: I used similar steps to create "tags" array with one more
> BeanShell Pre-Processor.

**STEP 3 (REQUEST PAYLOD):**

Then the Request Payload that the HTTP Sampler posts is as below:

```
{
  "included": {
    "groups": [
      "CANDY, GUM & MINTS",
      "TAKE HOME CANDY, GUM & MINTS",
      "SEASONAL CANDY, GUM & MINTS",
      "BULK CANDY/GUM/MINT -NS"
    ],
    "tags": [
      "ACME,ADAL,AIMT,AJWL,AKBA,ASHA,ASOC,AVMT,PSOC,RDAL,SACG,SDEN,SHAW,SHGN,SNCA,SPHO,SPRT,SSEA,SSPK,SWMA,VLAS,VSOC",
      "ACME,ADAL,AIMT,AJWL,ASHA,ASOC,AVMT,PSOC,RDAL,SACG,SHAW,SNCA,SPRT,SSEA,SSPK,SWMA,VSOC",
      "ACME,AKBA,SWMA",
      "ACME,ADAL,AIMT,AJWL,AKBA,ASHA,ASOC,AVMT,PSOC,RDAL,SACG,SDEN,SHAW,SHGN,SNCA,SPHO,SPRT,SSEA,SSPK,SWMA,UNTD,VLAS,VSOC"
    ]
  }
}
```

**STEP 4 - RESPONSE PAYLOD (WITH ERROR):**

However, I'm getting below error on the Response Payload for "groups" array and not for the "tags" array:

```
{"errorCode":"ISF","errorMessage":"JSON schema validation failed in 2 areas in included.groups - Array value found, but a null or an object is required"}
```

The only difference in these to arrays are that items within the "groups" array has special characters such as space, comma, ampersand, slash etc. Whereas, the "tags" do not have any special characters.

**- POINT TO BE NOTED:**

The test data contained in the sampleGroups.csv file has those special characters as per the raw data provided to me by my client. Because the data were ingested to the database as seen below, hence it has to have those characters to make like-for-like to prod data. And I need to send the Arrays with lists as it is.

```
sampleGroups.csv
"CANDY, GUM & MINTS"
"TAKE HOME CANDY, GUM & MINTS"
"SEASONAL CANDY, GUM & MINTS"
"BULK CANDY/GUM/MINT -NS"

sampleTags.csv
"ACME,ADAL,AIMT,AJWL,AKBA,ASHA,ASOC,AVMT,PSOC,RDAL,SACG,SDEN,SHAW,SHGN,SNCA,SPHO,SPRT,SSEA,SSPK,SWMA,VLAS,VSOC"
"ACME,ADAL,AIMT,AJWL,ASHA,ASOC,AVMT,PSOC,RDAL,SACG,SHAW,SNCA,SPRT,SSEA,SSPK,SWMA,VSOC"
"ACME,AKBA,SWMA"
"ACME,ADAL,AIMT,AJWL,AKBA,ASHA,ASOC,AVMT,PSOC,RDAL,SACG,SDEN,SHAW,SHGN,SNCA,SPHO,SPRT,SSEA,SSPK,SWMA,UNTD,VLAS,VSOC"
```

**WHAT I TRIED:**

I found 1 [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20335381/17867846) which did touch the issue related to JSON Schema validation. However, it is not applicable for my issue.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your system under test tells you where the problem is.

It expects a [JSON Object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp) (or null) and you're providing a [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) instead.

Maybe your system under test expects something like this:

```
{
  "included": {
    "groups": {
      "group1": ["CANDY", "GUM & MINTS"],
      "group2": ["TAKE HOME CANDY", "GUM & MINTS"],
      "group3": ["SEASONAL CANDY", "GUM & MINTS"],
      "group4": ["BULK CANDY/GUM/MINT -NS"]
    },
    "tags": {
      "tag1": ["ACME", "ADAL", "AIMT", "AJWL", "AKBA", "ASHA", "ASOC", "AVMT", "PSOC", "RDAL", "SACG", "SDEN", "SHAW", "SHGN", "SNCA", "SPHO", "SPRT", "SSEA", "SSPK", "SWMA", "VLAS", "VSOC"],
      "tag2": ["ACME", "ADAL", "AIMT", "AJWL", "ASHA", "ASOC", "AVMT", "PSOC", "RDAL", "SACG", "SHAW", "SNCA", "SPRT", "SSEA", "SSPK", "SWMA", "VSOC"],
      "tag3": ["ACME", "AKBA", "SWMA"],
      "tag4": ["ACME", "ADAL", "AIMT", "AJWL", "AKBA", "ASHA", "ASOC", "AVMT", "PSOC", "RDAL", "SACG", "SDEN", "SHAW", "SHGN", "SNCA", "SPHO", "SPRT", "SSEA", "SSPK", "SWMA", "UNTD", "VLAS", "VSOC"]
    }
  }
}
```

We cannot help you with converting your CSV data into JSON payload without seeing the JSON schema or example working request but one thing is obvious: you should [reconsider using Beanshell and switch to JSR223 PreProcessor with Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), the main reasons are:

- [Groovy has built-in JSON support](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html) so you won't have to manipulate raw strings
- Groovy supports modern Java language features and adds [even more syntax sugar on top](https://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html) while with Beanshell you're stuck with Java 5 language level
- Groovy scripts can be compiled and cached providing performance close to native Java code while Beanshell scripts are interpreted each time they're called. See [Beanshell vs. JSR223 vs. Java For JMeter: Complete Showdown](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter) for more information